# Merge [azure-openai] and [aoai]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The tags [azure-openai](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-openai) and [aoai](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aoai) seem synonymous. Let's merge them?

Comment: Done. There were only 2 questions which didn't have both tags (compared with 43 which had both) so clearly a redundant tag in the vast majority of cases. The tag is now just [tag:azure-openai].